# MySQL db storing date by zeros

Tags: mysql, date

I need to store date by zeros 000-00-00 like this, in my localhost server everything is fine, but when i uploaded to my hosting i getting error, if want to save zeros into db. How can resolve this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL `DATE` fields are limited [[1]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

With strict mode MySQL causes error to be caused when invalid date is inserted:

> As of 5.0.2, the server requires that month and day values be legal, and not merely in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode disabled, invalid dates such as '2004-04-31' are converted to '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. With strict mode enabled, invalid dates generate an error.

Although value `0000-00-00` should be permitted:

> As of MySQL 5.0.2, MySQL does not accept TIMESTAMP values that include a zero in the day or month column or values that are not a valid date. The sole exception to this rule is the special “zero” value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

If you didn't make a typo in your question and you are really inserting value `000-00-00`, on your server you probably get warning (silently discarded or stored somewhere in log) but on production you have strict mode enabled and since it's invalid date string you'll get the error.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
insert into <TableName>(<DateTimeField>) values('');
```